# Full screen flash content on two monitors?

Tags: flash, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I thought there was a simple way to make Flash content display full-screen on two monitors at once, but I can't seem to recall how to do it.

Searching on the topic is tough because so many people are talking about the ability to keep a full-screen video playing while working on another screen, which is not what I want.  I need an app I'm developing at 2880 x 900 to be viewable full-screen across two monitors horizontally.

I've tried

```
stage.displayState = "fullScreen";
```

activate from a user click, but it fills only one screen.

I've tried it from within a projector and from a browser with allowFullscreen set to true, and using version 10.2 of the player.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: That would be awesome. But I would rather think that this is what the user sets in the OS. How would the flash player know how many monitors there are? What if there are 3 or 4? Would the flash go full-full-fullscreen? I'm also curious on the right answer, good that you asked.

Comment: Good question.  I would think flash player would behave as it does when it has not enough content to show for a single monitor in fullscreen.  That is, to respect the scaleMode setting in order to determine how the extra space is used (or not)

Comment: I still think, that is outside the scope of the flash player. If you have 2 screens, you have to define whether you want to watch a movie on 1 screen, or split the video onto 2 screens. Splitting it, so to use the screens (monitors) as a mosaic is not trivial I think. So, as an answer, would you accept something like: "you have to set it in the OS"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, it seems unlikely that this is possible at the moment without addons.

What I've ended up doing is creating two distinct projectors that communicate via LocalConnection.

It's working well enough, though I'm hoping that Adobe will build in native support for this at some point in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is really no way of doing it. Even on other platforms, it really doesn't seem possible. As a constant dual screen user, this would be nice as fullscreen flash is rather buggy... Although in recent months, I have found that while using flash fullscreen, one can use the other screen to work on without the first screen resizing to standard. I am sharing your pain.

Kind Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you'll need a third party swf2exe tool. I make a product that lets you do this. SWF Studio lets you enable "multiple monitor support" with a single checkbox in the UI that makes your projector window will fill the entire virtual display when you go fullscreen.

What you do on that large canvas is up to you. If you try to fill the virtual display with video be prepared to pay performance pernalties. That's a lot of screen to cover with video.

See the last checkbox on this screen to enable multiple monitor support
http://www.northcode.com/v3/help/index.html?page=User%20Interface_Main%20%20Window%20Tab.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, it turns out I need something that can be authored and run on OS X.